# Select elements in an array where elements in another array are true

Tags: c#, linq, boolean

As I said in the title: I need to select elements in an array in the position where elements in another array are true. The same result I'd have with Matlab command:

```
output = array1(array2);
```

Where array2 is an array of bools.

I'm lost in Linq at the moment :)

Comment: So for example if array1 is `{ "a", "b", "c" }` and array2 is `{ false, true, true }` the result would be `{ "b", "c" }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's an overload of [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) extension method taking an `Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate` as second argument.

The `int` paremeter in the `Func<TSource, int, bool>` is the index of the source.

```
output = array1.Where((x, index) => array2[index]);
```

Comment: Thank you! It needs a .toArray() at the end :)

Comment: @Marco if you need an array as result, yes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var bools = new[] { true, false };
var elements = new[] { 1, 2 };
var result = elements
    .Take(bools.Length)
    .Where((e, index) => bools[index]).ToList();
```

The `Take` method ensures that the element search is made in the index range of the `bools` array.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, you could write a custom extension method - for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereEnabled<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<bool> flags)
{
    using(var sourceIter = source.GetEnumerator())
    using(var flagIter = flags.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while(sourceIter.MoveNext() && flagIter.MoveNext())
        {
            if (flagIter.Current) yield return sourceIter.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

then just:

```
var enabled = array1.WhereEnabled(array2);
```

perhaps with the vector specialization:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereEnabled<T>(
    this T[] source,
    bool[] flags)
{
    int max = Math.Min(source.Length, flags.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++ )
    {
        if (flags[i]) yield return source[i];
    }
}
```